# Pandas return df with repeated data ranges for element of list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a df with data range values.
I can create the df like this:

```
def create_df(start='2021-01-01', end='2022-12-31'):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range(start,end)})
    return df
df = create_df()
```

Gives the following df

```
    Date
0   2021-01-01
1   2021-01-02
2   2021-01-03
3   2021-01-04
4   2021-01-05
```

Now I want to create a second column A with elements from a list. There should be one df with repeated date values for each element of the list.
This is what I want

```
        Date    A
0   2021-01-01  1
1   2021-01-02  1
2   2021-01-03  1
    .............
729 2022-12-31  1
730 2021-01-01  2
```

How can I create one df with the repeated data range for all element in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for repeat values of lists with date ranges:

```
from  itertools import product
def create_df(start='2021-01-01', end='2022-12-31', L=[1,2,3]):
    df = pd.DataFrame(product(L,  pd.date_range(start,end)), columns=['A','Date'])
    return df[['Date','A']]
df = create_df()

print (df)
           Date  A
0    2021-01-01  1
1    2021-01-02  1
2    2021-01-03  1
3    2021-01-04  1
4    2021-01-05  1
        ... ..
2185 2022-12-27  3
2186 2022-12-28  3
2187 2022-12-29  3
2188 2022-12-30  3
2189 2022-12-31  3

[2190 rows x 2 columns]
```